# A function not constant on a connected set of critical points?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I was looking for a function differentiable on a set, such that every point would be critical, and still the function would not be constant(everywhere).

I found [this reference](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-2972-8_19)

If someone has access to this paper, I would greatly appreciate it.

I think it's different from other question on this site, where they were allowing for zero derivative-a.e. functions, and I'm not...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you can read this article on google books (https://books.google.fr/books?id=qPA6LEjOR4kC&pg=PA290&lpg=PA290&dq=A+Function+Not+Constant+on+a+Connected+Set+of+Critical+Points&source=bl&ots=O7n1PQ2xxx&sig=ujZ8NdKjowjJQi8YhTGaOHl2Wsw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX_bPNpYfQAhXD0RoKHR_EBXsQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=A%20Function%20Not%20Constant%20on%20a%20Connected%20Set%20of%20Critical%20Points&f=false), around page $515$

Comment: @charMD thanks for the comments, but it seems some pages are not available for consultation...

Comment: Indeed, I'm sorry, the first time I went on this page, I could read the whole 5 pages but it seems the link does not work that well.

Comment: I think that, instead of using the link above, if you google "A Function Not Constant on a Connected Set of Critical Points", and go to the google books page which is proposed (named "Hassler Whitney Collected Papers Volume 1"), you can read it

Comment: I will try to make an answer out of this and post it here in place of the link, but I don't know if I will have the time

Comment: @charMD I would appreciate it a lot!! ;)

Comment: By the way, you mention connectedness in your title but not in the main text - just to be sure - was this indeed the main point of your question ?

Comment: @charMD The main point was to find a function with derivative equal to zero everywhere, but not constant. The title has "connected" since it's in the title of the article which seems to have an answer to my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47836/discussion-between-charmd-and-an-old-man-in-the-sea).