# Must a differentiable function $f$ be constant if $f'$ is always $0$ and the domain is connected?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $m,n\in\Bbb N$, with $n\ne1$, let $A$ be a non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, let $f\colon A\longrightarrow\Bbb R^m$ be a differentiable function, and let $C$ be a connected subset of $A$ such that, for each $p\in C$, $f'(p)$ is the null function. Does it follow that $f$ is constant on $C$?

In the previous question, $n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$ since the statement is clearly true when $n=1$; it's a classical theorem that follows from the [mean value theorem for vector-valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions).

And if $C$ is open, it is also true. The function $f$ will have to be locally constant since (from which it follows that it is constant, since $C$ is connected), if $p\in C$ and $r>0$ are such that $B_r(p)\subset C$, then, for each $q\in B_r(p)$, the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\hat f:&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^m\\&t&\mapsto&f\bigl(tp+(1-t)q\bigr)\end{array}$$is differentiable and $\hat f'$ is the null function. More generally, by a similar argument, the statement is true if $C$ is arcwise connected, as long as those arcs are differentiable or, at least, piecewise differentiable.

But I would like to know whether or not it holds in general.

Comment: @rubikscube09 you forgot the factor $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: If $f$ is $C^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ and $W_t$ is an $n$-dimensional standard Brownian motion, then Ito's lemma tells us that $f(W_t) - f(W_0) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \Delta f(W_s)ds$. Not sure if this works but it is what I first imagined if $C$ is not a piecewise smooth curve. In particular it may be the case that $\nabla f$ is $0$ on $C$ but not $\Delta f$.

Comment: If I understand [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/157939/4678) correctly, the claim does **not** hold in general (because of a 1935 counterexample by Whitney, involving the von Koch snowflake or something similar).

Comment: @HansLundmark This totally answers my question! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks to 
@HansLundmark's comment I found this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994238/a-function-not-constant-on-a-connected-set-of-critical-points) im MSE. Maybe some information in it are helpful.

Comment: @mag That post has a link to the same article by Hassler Whitney as the [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/157939/4678) mentioned above.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Why not post a brief CW answer in which you link to the MO answer, and then accept it, in order to get your question out of the unanswered questions list?

Comment: @AlexM. Nice suggestion! I will do that.